# delete map from Firestore swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My `Firestore` db has the following structure:

**inventory** (The main collections)

**food** (A document with the collection)

**id : 1** (A field..)

**products** (map which contains products)

**fish** (map which contains information about the fish product)

**id** (a field with the id of the fish)

Here's an example of two products:

`inventory/food/products/fish`

`inventory/food/products/meat`

I wish to delete, for instance, the map `meat` from the `products` list.

I'm using the following code:

```
func deleteProductFromDb()
{
    if let firestoreDb = self.firestoreDb
    {
        firestoreDb.collection("inventory").document("food").updateData(["products.meat": FieldValue.delete()])
    }
}
```

I'm getting no error, but the `meat` map is not deleted from the db.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a collection as you described.

[image]

Here is how you can delete the map `"meat"`:

```
let FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

let docRef = db.collection('inventory').doc('food');

let removeField = docRef.set({'products':
    {['meat'] : FieldValue.delete()}}, {merge: true});
```